# When responding to thank you, is it anytime or any time?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

When responding to "Thank you", is it "Anytime" or "Any time"?

Most web pages I look at had "anytime" but I wonder if "any time" is wrong.

Comment: It would never be wrong to use _any time_.

Answer (score 1):

[Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/e/anytime-vs-any-time/) says to use "any time" in this context.

The difference between "anytime" and "any time" is that "anytime" is an adverb, and "any time" is a noun phrase. So "any time" follows a preposition, as in "You can call me at any time", and "anytime" modifies a verb, as in "You can call me anytime". However it is also appropriate to use the noun "any time" instead of "anytime", such as "You can call me any time" (sometimes you can use a noun phrase without a preposition to refer to a point or period in time, as in "You can call me next week.") This is why "always use any time" is a good rule for language learners, even if native speakers will sometimes use "anytime".

While "anytime" can sometimes be used in situations, many sources recommend always using "any time" in formal writing. ([Thought.co](https://www.thoughtco.com/any-time-or-anytime-4165124))

But in this instance, where "any time"/"anytime" is not part of a sentence, it isn't obvious what part of speech you want, so you have to follow convention and do what the dictionaries or grammar texts tell you.